# How to detect Backbone.History referer (history length)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history, backbone-routing

I'm developing a Backbone application with multiple views, collections, etc..
It also has a router that handles permanent URL pretty well.

What I'm trying to achieve is creating a "Back" button which allows user to go back `window.history(-1)` to a previous view when it is available (user came from that view earlier). And if not, the "back" button would lead to the home page.

Basically I need to check whether or not Backbone has saved something in its history I can use to roll back one step. If the history is empty (we navigated to this URL directly) back point to the main router.

I already tried using `window.hisory.length` but it is never empty. It may still point to the starting homepage of the browser or browser's blank opening page.

**Does Backbone.History keeps track of the URLs (hashes) that passes through it?** If so - how to I access it. I already tried console logging Backbone.History but found nothing I can hold on to.

Any help / advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Router initialise function -

```
this.on("all", this.storeRoute);
this.history = [];
```

Then the storeRoute function (also in router) -

```
storeRoute: function() {
    return this.history.push(Backbone.history.fragment);
}
```

The also in router -

```
previous: function(){
    if (this.history.length > 1) {
      return this.navigate(this.history[this.history.length - 2], true);
    }
}
```

So, then you can just call `yourApp.router.previous()` at any time!